# AngularJS Karma Jasmine unit tests for nested $q.when().finally()

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-promise

Quite a newbie to AngularJS, and have researched a half day on how to mock

```
$q.when().finally()
```

but didn't get any good answers.

Here's the code i want to unit test

```
angular.module('some-module').service('some-service', [
    'a_workflow',
    'b_api',
    function(Workflow, Api) {
        this.prepareToEnterFlow = function(forward, flowContext, pageContext, transitionData, callback) {
            $q.when().finally(function() { 
                 $q.when().finally(function() {
                     pageContext.data.XXX = foo();
                     if (_.isEmpty(pageContext.data.XXX)) {
                         ....
                     }
                 });
            });
        }
    }
]);
```

Any idea on how to mock/stub the nested $q.when()? Need to test some logics at both levels. (e.g. to check if pageContext.data.XXX is empty)

Comment: Not sure if this applies to your use case, but my best guess is that the `.when()` call hangs up you do not pass a value, or if that value is `undefined`.

Comment: Hey, how's it going man :)